# Outputting parallel --pipe to file

Tags: bash, unix, gnu-parallel

I am using the below command in bash, which writes the output from bcftools via `>` to the desired file

```
bcftools reheader -s samples.txt input_file.vcf > output_file.vcf
```

I want to use parallel to perform this on several files, tried the below but doesn't quite work...

```
parallel --pipe bcftools reheader -s samples.txt input_file.{}.vcf -f out_file.{}.vcf ::: {01..10}
```

How do I write the STDOUT from each parallel process to individual files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is that you want to use a `>` inside the command you pass to **GNU Parallel**, you can do that by single quoting the command:

```
parallel 'doSomething > {}.log' ::: a b c
```

or escaping:

```
parallel doSomething \> {}.log ::: a b c
```

Comment: But also try: parallel --results mydir bcftools reheader -s samples.txt input_file.{}.vcf -f out_file.{}.vcf ::: {01..10}